# Weird mapping error in linq-to-sql dbml file in VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql

Since I switched to VS2010, several times a day I get a compilation error in my dbml file:

```
DBML1005: Mapping between DbType 'bigint' and Type
'MyNamespace.SecurityToken' in Column 'SecurityToken' of Type
'Employee' is not supported
```

When I restart VS2010 the error disappears. I have no problems running my application using this dbml file (specifically, there are no problems getting correct values inside the `SecurityToken` property of `Employee` objects).

The `SecurityToken` property is of an enum type defined as follows:

```
[Flags]
public enum SecurityToken : long
{
    None = 1,
    Admin = 2,
    ......
}
```

The `SecurityToken` column in the database is of type `bigint`.

Am I missing something? It's especially weird that the error only happens sometimes, when I'm writing code that isn't related at all to the LINQ model.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems this is a LINQ bug when resolving the enums. The workaround is to add the `global::` prefix.

A necessary mapping for this in your DBML file may look like:

```
<Column Name="SecurityToken" Type="global::MyNamespace.SecurityToken" 
        DbType="BigInt NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" />
```

Of cause, you could do the same using designer.

Comment: Alternatively, declare the enum in the same namespace as the DataContext.  IIRC, this 'bug' was present in VS2008 too.

Comment: @leppie: it's interesting sometimes mapping works fine without using the global keyword but sometimes...

Comment: I'll try it and report back if the problem no longer occurs. Thanks.

Comment: same stuff happens 11 years later in VS 2019